# How to set location coordinates of that city when a button with city name is pressed in google places api in nextjs web application?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, geolocation, google-places-api

I'm  building a **NextJs** web app where the user can explore various stores near him.
I'm using **google places Api** to select location from the places dropdown.
Based on the location the stores are displayed.
Rather typing the location I want a buttons with city name which on click will set the location of that city.

***Here search bar and get current location button is present along with
city button***

**Location.tsx**

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    if(!getLocation?.formattedAddress){
        setLocation(true);
        setHasLoction(false);
    }else{
        setHasLoction(true);
    }
},[])

 function changeLocation(data:any){
   
    var location=JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data?.formattedAddress);
    document.getElementById("location_id").value=data?.formattedAddress;
    setLocation(data?.formattedAddress);

    if(location){
        setHasLoction(true);
        // closeLocation(); 
    }

    var {query ,pathname} = router;
    var pathname="/"+router.locale+pathname
    
    router.push(
    {
        pathname,
        query: query,
    },
    {
        pathname,
        query: query,
    },
    );
    handleLocation()
}


return (

<div style={{zIndex: 1000}}  className={`absolute  flex flex-col  w-full z-1000 inset-0 shadow-lg transform ml-0 duration-200 ease-in 
                                ${location ? ' translate-y-0 ' : '-translate-y-full' }  transform border-5 bg-gray-100 h-screen lg:h-100 xl:h-110 2xl:h-110 overflow-y-hidden overflow-hidden `}>
                                  
                                   <div className='border-red-400 flex w-full'>
                                       <div className='flex flex-col'>
                                           <h4 className='block lg:hidden text-sm sm:text-2xl md:text-3xl lg:text-4xl mx-4 sm:mx-16 md:mx-16 mt-8 text-magenta font-heading font-semibold'>
                                               
                                           </h4>
                                           <div className=''>
                                               <p className=' lg:hidden flex mx-4  sm:mx-16 md:mx-16 mt-4 font-semibold items-center text-xs 
                                               xs+:text-sm sm:text-sm text-gray-700'>
                                                   Local stores </p>
                                               <p className=' lg:hidden flex mx-4 sm:mx-16 md:mx-16 mt-0 font-semibold items-center text-xs 
                                                              xs+:text-sm sm:text-sm text-gray-700'>
                                                  </p>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <img src='/drop-down.jpg' className='hidden lg:block md:relative object-fill md:object-contain'/>
                                   </div>

                                    {/* <HeaderMiddle/> */}
                        <div className='flex items-center justify-between mx-auto mt-20 '>

                            {/* <Logo className="mx-auto" /> */}
                            <img src="/icons/x.svg"  onClick = {closeLocation} 
                                 style={{zIndex: 100}} className={`${(hasLocation)?"":"hidden"} absolute font-bold z-40 h-7 w-7 top-2 bg-gold  rounded-full right-2 2xl:top-5 text-gray-400 2xl:h-8  2xl:w-8 2xl:right-7 `}/>
                            {/* <h2 className=' font-md text-md sm:text-lg md:text-lg lg:text-lg 2xl:text-2xl '> Get best deals in your name </h2> */}

                        </div>
                        {/* <img src='/drop-down.jpg' className='relative   top-0 object-contain'/> */}
                        
                        <div id='location-input' style={{zIndex: 0}} 
                             className='absolute flex flex-col justify-center 
                                   w-full lg:w-full items-center  pt-36  sm:pt-20 md:pt-4 lg:pt-0 space-y-6 ml-0 mx-3 
                                   sm:mx-16 md:ml-16 lg:ml-6 xl:ml-8 2xl:ml-10 lg:mt-80'> 
                                      
                            <div  style = {{zIndex: 1000}}  
                                  className='w-full'> 
                                <GooglePlacesAutocomplete onChange = {changeLocation} 
                                                          address  = 
          {getLocation?.formattedAddress} /> 
                            </div>
    
                            <div style={{zIndex: 1000}}  className='w-full'> 
                                 <GetCurrentLocation onChange = {changeLocation} />  
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div className='-mt-10'>
                            <button onClick={setCityLocation}
                            className='p-2 border'>
                                New York
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        
                    {/* <Dialog.Overlay className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-900 bg- 
    opaname-80 w-full h-full" /> */}
                       
            </div>
```

**google-places-autocomplete.tsx**

```
import { Autocomplete, useJsApiLoader } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import { Libraries } from "@react-google-maps/api/dist/utils/make-load-script-url";
import { LocationInput } from "@ts-types/generated";
import React, { useState ,useEffect } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import Loader from "@components/ui/loader/loader";
 import { useLocation } from "@contexts/location/location.context";
 import { useCreateLogMutation } from "@data/log/use-create-log.mutation";
 import useOnClickOutside from "@utils/use-click-outside";


const libraries: Libraries = ["places"];
// data,
// data: LocationInput;
 export default function GooglePlacesAutocomplete({address,
   onChange
 }: {
onChange: any;
 address :any
 }) {
 const { t } = useTranslation();
 const [loc,setLocation]=useState(address);
 const { mutate: createLog, isLoading: loading } = useCreateLogMutation();

 const { isLoaded, loadError } = useJsApiLoader({
 id: "google_map_autocomplete",
 googleMapsApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY!,
 libraries,
 });

  const [autocomplete, setAutocomplete] = React.useState<any>(null);

  const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(autocompleteInstance) {
  setAutocomplete(autocompleteInstance);
 }, []);

  const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback() {
   setAutocomplete(null);
  }, []);


   const onPlaceChanged = () => {
  const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
    console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
  }


  setLocation(place.formatted_address);
  const location: any = {
  lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
  lng: place.geometry.location.lng(),
  formattedAddress: place.formatted_address,
 };

  for (const component of place.address_components) {
  // @ts-ignore remove once typings fixed
  const componentType = component.types[0];

    switch (componentType) {
    case "postal_code": {
      location["zip"] = component.long_name;
      break;
     }

     case "postal_code_suffix": {
      location["zip"] = `${location?.zip}-${component.long_name}`;
      break;
    }

     case "locality":
      location["city"] = component.long_name;
      break;

     case "administrative_area_level_1": {
       location["state"] = component.short_name;
       break;
    }

     case "country":
      location["country"] = component.long_name;
       break;
   }
 }

 if (onChange) {
    onChange(location);

   createLog({location:location.formattedAddress}, {
    onSuccess: (data: any) => {
        console.log(data)
    },
      onError: (error: any) => {
       
     },
    });
     }
   };

 if (loadError) {
 return <div>{t("common:text-map-cant-load")}</div>;
 }

  return isLoaded ? (
  
   <Autocomplete
    onLoad={onLoad}
    onPlaceChanged={onPlaceChanged}
    onUnmount={onUnmount}
    fields={["address_components", "geometry.location", "formatted_address"]}
    types={["address"]}
    className="flex"
    >

    <input
      type = "text"
      defaultValue={loc}
      style={{borderRadius:"5px"}}
      className="p-3 pl-8  mx-8 w-full  sm:px-8 sm:w-full sm:mx-auto  xmd:mx-4 md:w- 
      full md:mx-auto 
                  2xl:p-3 lg:p-3 lg:mx-auto  lg:w-full 2xl:w-full 2xl:mx-auto font- 
         light
                  focus:border-accent focus:bg-light bg-gray-80
                  outline-none text-xs sm:text-sm md:text-base lg:text-lg 
                border-gray-300 border "
    />

  </Autocomplete >

   ) : (

 <div className="flex">
  <Loader simple={true} className="w-6 h-6" />
 </div>
 );
}
```